# Identify this large exotic bird spotted in Taipei, Taiwan

Tags: ornithology, species-identification

A few months ago while backpacking in Taipei I found this very intriguing large bird facing off a curious puppy in a fairly busy pedestrian area.

The bird did not attempt to fly. None of the Taiwanese locals could tell me what it was and attempts to Google it via description all failed.

I'd appreciate learning the species name, common name in English, and/or common name in Chinese:

[image: mystery bird in Taipei, Taiwan]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it looks like a [Malayan Night Heron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayan_night_heron), *Gorsachius melanolophus*.

They seems to be common in this part of Asia, see the [distribution](https://www.oiseaux.net/maps/malayan.night.heron.html).

It looks strange because he probably get scared.

Comment: It seems to resemble the birds in [this photo online](http://wildbird.e-land.gov.tw/wildbird/AAA/photo/%E6%9D%8E%E9%BE%8D%E5%A2%89%20%20%E9%BB%91%E5%86%A0%E9%BA%BB%E9%B7%BA-3\(2\).jpg). It's labelled "黑冠麻鷺", which seems to be the Chinese translation for "Malayan night heron".